# Make Cortana Skill listen longer

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

at the moment I am developing a Cortana skill with .net & C# and MS-BotFramework, which should primarily run on the Invoke from Harman. 
So far everything fits. However, I would like to increase the time the skill listens. 
So far I have only found one way for UWP to increase this time (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/input/set-speech-recognition-timeouts). Unfortunately, this doesn't help me with my Cortana skill - because I want to deploy it as a Cortana skill and not as an UWP app.

Now my question: Is there generally a way to increase the time the Cortana skill waits for an answer from the user?

Thanks for help!,

PG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the skill does not control the timeout or interaction time with the Cortana channel (the app.)  I have worked around this by setting up async timer tasks that use replaceDialog to change the dialog flow, and/or prompt again. Unfortunately, dialog flow works a bit differently in C# (so I do not have an example).  However, on Invoke, reprompts happen automatically. On Windows 10/Mobile, because there is a card, they don't (as the card should still be visible). Please add the suggestion to add this feature via the feedback hub (via Windows start/search menu). Please also send me a note if you want to continue the discussion.

Comment: I agree with Micromuncher in that there is no option to change the Cortana skills listening time, as of yet.

Comment: @Micromuncher: Thank you for your answer. It is really a pity that this is not yet realizable, as it would extend the possibilities of the skill. My focus is on the Invoke, but a realization with Win 10/Mobile is also interesting - you said that there is a card that could be used to realize it on these devices, what is it?

Comment: Hi Peter.  I am referring to the cortana canvas that is displayed to provide visual feedback.  I use 'card' because we use several types of formats ( rich cards or adaptive cards) to display content.